# PintOS user program does not print

Tags: operating-system, kernel, pintos

Im trying to follow this guide, the section about user programs. Apparently, Im able to succesfully pass a program from ubuntu to the Pintos filesystem, because I can see the file by running `pintos -q ls`

[image: Output of pintos -q ls]

When runnning this:

```
pintos-mkdisk filesys.dsk --filesys-size=2
pintos -f -q
pintos -p ../../examples/echo -a echo -- -q
pintos -q run 'echo x'
```

I only get this, and no printing:

[image: Running the echo program inside pintos]

Any idea of why not seeing the output? I've also tried with the "hellopintos" file, which is simply a hello world like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <syscall.h>

    void main(){
       printf("Hello pintos\n");

    }
```

Comment: the guide: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs140/projects/pintos/pintos_3.html

Comment: Description of the code you use: "Here's a summary of how to create a disk with a file system partition, format the file system, copy the `echo` program into the new disk, and then run `echo`, passing argument x." So this is a code for the `echo` command, not for your program.

Comment: The exact same thing happens when running my program with `pintos -q run 'hellopintos'` . After the creation. Anyways, shouldn't the echo program(which is under src/examples folder) give an output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the syscall handler was not implemented on userprog/syscall.c
After implementing it and handling the write/print case, the issue was resolved.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on how you fixed it? Even if printf syscall is not implemented shouldn't it have output "Syscall not implemented" instead of terminating blank?